# Ошибка сannot find name Nuxt Typescript

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

Установил пакеты по [инструкции](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup.html) Nuxt Typescript.

Но при выполнении команды:

```
npm run dev
```

Получаю ошибку `Cannot find name 'moment'. Аналогично с lodash: Cannot find name '_'`

Файл `tsconfig.json` скопирован из инструкции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

В папку **plugins** добавил файл **.js**, в котором прописал следующее:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
import * as _ from "lodash";

declare global {
  const moment: typeof Moment
  const _: typeof Object
}
```